# Memcache implementation design

Tags: java, caching, memcached

Iam trying to implement memcache in my web application and just wanted to get suggestions that whether what iam doing is right in terms of design.

I have a class SimpleDataAccessor which run all my insert, update and select sql queries. So any query that has to be performed is executed inside the method of this class.

So inside the method where I have my select query implementation i have a method which stores the resultset in memcache like this.

**storeinMC(resultset.getJSON(),sqlquery);**

*the sqlquery here is my key.*

Also before running the selectquery i check in memcache that whether I have a resultset already for that query.

**if((String res=getRSFromMC(sqlquery)==null)**

So i've tried to keep it plain and simple. 
Do you see any issues with this.?

Comment: Can you make sure that your sql querry is unique for it to be the key? What about typos/extra spaces in your query...

Comment: Yes i suppose it would be unique. Every fetch from DB would be unique right; if you think. If its not then we are getting the same data for which we would get the value already there in memcache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rai.skumar rightfully pointed out your SQL statements could be constructed differently (e.g. WHERE clause could contain same conditions in diff order, etc.)

So to overcome above mentioned issues, you need to parse your SQL and get all the relevant pieces from it. Then you can combine these pieces into a cache key.

You can take a look at SQL parsers: [ZQL](http://zql.sourceforge.net/), [JSqlParser](http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/), [General SQL Parser for Java](http://www.sqlparser.com/sql-parser-java.php) that return you java classes out of your SQL.

Another option would be to use [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jpa-137156.html) instead of straight JDBC. For example [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) has great JPA support and fully capable of caching your queries.

If you feel closer to JDBC you could use [MyBatis](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/) that has very JDBC like syntax and caching support.

Comment: Thanks for this. Really helpful. I guess its not easy designing an effective memcache design when you have complex sql queries running.

Comment: No problem! if it was a useful answer, don't forget to click UP arrow!

Comment: Tried; but I guess I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below queries:

```
 String k1 = "Select * from table";   //Query1
 String k2 = "Select * from TABLE";  // Query2 ; notice TABLE is in caps
```

Both of above SQL queries are same and will fetch same data. But if above queries are used as keys in Memchached they will get stored at different places ( as k1.equals(k2) will return false).

Also if somehow you can ensure that there are no typos or extra spaces, it won't be very efficient as keys/queries could be very big.

Comment: I get it. It can work for small queries where I can control the caps and other typos. Can you suggest a better implementation with this design. What can i use as keys in this case.

Comment: main constraint is key part only. Memchached works similar to HashMap i.e. key gets mapped to corresponding value. So just make sure that your key design is proper and you can keep anything in value.